# リストの特定の要素に文字を挿入したい

Tags: java

閲覧ありがとうございます。

#### 質問者のレベル

プログラミングの勉強を始めて2週間目です。

#### 実現したいこと

下記の体重測定csvを読み込んでリストに格納し、測定結果の数値の前に「約」を付けたいです。
リストに格納するところまではできたのですが、どうやって上記の処理を行えばよいのかわかりません。
回答よろしくお願いします。
(Beanは省略します)

#### csv

```
田中,欠席
山田,測定結果：78kg
葛城,欠席
高橋,測定結果：88kg
加藤,測定結果：54kg
小林,欠席
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
List<List<Bean>> listOfList = new ArrayList<List<Bean>>();
String line = "";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  //brはbufferedReaderのインスタンス
　　　　
       String[] array = line.split(",");
　　　　List<String>list = new ArrayList<String>();
       list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));

　　　　Bean bean = new Bean();
       bean.setName(list.get(0));
       bean.setWeight(list.get(1));

       List<Bean> listOfBean = new ArrayList<Bean>();
       listOfBean.add(bean);
       listOfList.add(listOfBean);
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/164493

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> どうやって上記の処理を行えばよいのかわかりません

上記の例を見ると、`array[1]`の値は「欠席」か「測定結果：XYZkg」の２パターンがある。`array[1]`に、「測定結果：」の文字列を「測定結果：約」に変更すれば、期待されている結果を得ることができます。例えば、次のように：

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] array = line.split(",");
  array[1] = array[1].replaceAll("^測定結果：", "測定結果：約");

  Bean bean = new Bean();
  bean.setName(array[0]);
  bean.setWeight(array[1]);

  List<Bean> listOfBean = new ArrayList<>();
  listOfBean.add(bean);
  listOfList.add(listOfBean);
}
```

`array[1]`（か、`bean.getWeight()`）を出力すると：

> ```
> 欠席
> 測定結果：約78kg
> 欠席
> 測定結果：約88kg
> 測定結果：約54kg
> 欠席
> ```

Comment: 「約」をどうやって挿入しようかと考えていましたが、replaceで置き換えるという手段があるのですね。勉強不足でした。ありがとうございました。